# Thread sanitizer issue in Xcode with atomic/synchronized properties & NSLock

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, synchronized

I have a property declared on an object in Objective-C that's called from multiple threads:

`@property (atomic, strong) NSNumber *validLock;`

In my setter, I do the following:

```
@synchronized(self.validLock) {
   self.validLock = @YES;
}
```

In my getter, I do the following:

```
@synchronized(self.validLock) {
   if (self.validLock.boolValue) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Despite all these precautions, the thread sanitizer in Xcode still breaks on the `@synchronized` getter line with a comment "Data Race detected."

I even ditched the '@synchronized' idea and went all-in with `NSLock` to no avail.

This is becoming laughable, as this also gets tagged on `[myLock lock]` by the Xcode thread sanitizer:

```
NSLock *myLock = [[NSLock alloc] init];
...
[myLock lock];
self.validLock = @NO;
[myLock unlock];
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't particularly meaningful:

```
@synchronized(self.validLock) {
   self.validLock = @YES;
}
```

I think you're expecting this to synchronize on "the `validLock` property of `self`" but that's not what the parameter means. You're synchronizing on the `NSNumber` that is currently pointed to by `validLock` (an `NSNumber` that you then replace). Since this is not the same object that you synchronize against elsewhere, this doesn't do much.

Similarly, if this code is all in the same context (which is what your example suggests), it doesn't do anything either:

```
NSLock *myLock = [[NSLock alloc] init];
...
[myLock lock];
self.validLock = @NO;
[myLock unlock];
```

Each thread would have its own lock.

First, you really want to avoid both `NSLock` and `@synchronized`. They've been superseded by GCD for many years now. See the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1) for full details.

If you really want to use `@synchronized` (realizing that it is pretty inflexible and quite slow), then typically you call it on `self`.

```
@synchronized(self) {
   self.validLock = @YES;
}
```

But in any case, it has to be on the same actual object (not just the same name of an object).

If you're going to use `NSLock`, you need to make sure everyone is sharing the same actual lock, so for a single instance it needs to be a property. For multiple instances it needs to be a global or at least a class property.